# Adding printer, installing and Printing with canon LBP2900 in ubuntu 14.04 LTS! New to UBUNTU! please help!

Tags: 14.04, drivers, printing

I am using Ubuntu 14.04L and my printer is a Canon lbp2900b.

I have tried a number of methods I found in ubuntu help pages, forums and community! After following some instructions I was able to install my printer. Somewhy, it still doesn't print anything.

Some one please help me by giving the right procedure to add, configure, install or whatever that i need to do to make my canon lbp 2900b to work with ubuntu 14.04!

Comment: Tell us what you already did and what not.

Comment: Can you please add a little more detail? (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Possible duplicate [Printing problem , Canon LBP2900](/q/326620/175814)